# animated image disappeared after table view scrolled

Tags: ios, sdwebimage

I am working with one iOS application it has one table view. table view cell has a button, I use `SDWebimage` to process image. the animated image on the button disappeared after table view scroll.

iOS version: 12.2

SDWebImage version: 5.4.4

xcode version: 11.3

demo project link：https://github.com/relaxfinger/SDWebImageDemo.git

screen shot link: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1cEGYsnFdpOh4xgfML5dk59S8iiVlhmfC/view?usp=sharing

Code:

```
- (nonnull UITableViewCell *)tableView:(nonnull UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(nonnull NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    TableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"TableViewCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    if (indexPath.row > 0) {
        [cell.button setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"ic_placehold_font"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    } else {
        [cell.button sd_setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://images.ypcang.com/1575890250112.png"]
                forState:UIControlStateNormal
        placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"ic_placehold_font"]];
    }

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: image is loading only to the first row, what is the problem?

Comment: when scroll table view some times, the animated image in first row will disappear occasionally